# Does the "Votes" tab really serve a purpose?

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow, questions, sorting

There's a tab on Stack Overflow for questions called "Votes" that shows the questions that have recieved the most votes. The problem is it includes *all* questions. I've been a member on Stack Overflow for almost 2 years, and the same questions that were on top back when I first joined are still there. I know the free e-books question is helpful, but really whats the point of it?

Maybe it should only include questions that have received the most votes by month or something? Maybe we should at least add the option to select the time frame of the questions displayed? Or is there a reason they kept it like this? Really, I have not found it very useful the way it stands.

Comment: It is incredibly useful for new users, but yes, the option to view timeframes should be more visible

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's useful when you're doing more restricted searches, since you can narrow the number of questions down, then sort them by votes.

Comment: you win, experient sir. :P

Answer (score 10):

You're talking about this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=votes

But if you go to the [main page](http://stackoverflow.com), there's already the same idea sorted by [week](https://stackoverflow.com/?tab=week) or [month](https://stackoverflow.com/?tab=month).

While I agree the Votes tab might [seem like useless](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91056/does-the-votes-tab-really-serve-a-purpose/91061#91061) to long time users, if nothing less it does work as a reference of the community somehow, even while most of them might be there "just for historical significance". It's a good parameter to check when you go to a new [SEN](https://stackexchange.com/legal) site.

Comment: except half of them say: "This question exists because it has historical significance, but it is not considered a good, on-topic question for this site"

Comment: haha @Andy - excellent point! Thanks, I've fixed my point. :)